# How to restart Erlang Supervised function with parameters?

Tags: erlang, erlang-supervisor

I'm learning Erlang, and have a Supervisor question...

I have a function which requires 3 parameters (string, string, number).  I want to Supervise that and make sure that if it fails, it gets restarted with the 3 parameters I passed it.

Is this something a Supervisor can handle, or do I need to look into some other concept?

Thanks.

**Update 1/23/2016**

One thing I want to mention... I have a list of 1439 entries. I need to create a Supervisor for each entry in that list.  Each entry will incur different arguments.  For example, here's some psuedo-code (reminiscent of Ruby):

```
(360..1799).each do |index|
  export(output_path, table_name, index) # Supervise this
end
```

This is triggered by a user interaction at runtime. The `output_path` and `table_name` are dynamic too, but won't change for a given batch. Unravelled, a run may look something like this:

```
export("/output/2016-01-23/", "temp1234", 360)
export("/output/2016-01-23/", "temp1234", 361)
export("/output/2016-01-23/", "temp1234", 362)
.
.
```

So if 361 fails, I need it restarted with `"/output/2016-01-23/"`, `temp1234`, and `361`.

Is this something I can do with a Supervisor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is what `supervisor` does, but you mean "arguments", not "parameters".

For ordinary (not simple_one_for_one) supervisors your init/1 implementation returns a list of so called child specifications, each of which specifies a child that will be spawned, and the arguments that will be passed are provided as part of this child specification.

With simple_one_for_one supervisors you still have to provide a child specification, but you provide the arguments when you start each supervised child.

In all cases your supervised children will be restarted with the same arguments.

Answer (score 0):

#### General Concepts

- Erlang systems are divided into **modules**.
- Each module are composed of **functions**.
- Works are done by **processes** and they use functions to do it.
- A **supervisor** is a process which supervises other processes.

So your function will sure be executed inside a process, and you can specify and supervise that process by a supervisor. This way when your function fails and crashes, the process that are executing it will crash as well. When the process crashes, its supervisor will find out and can act upon it based on a predefined *restart strategy*. These strategies could be `one_for_one`, `one_for_all` and `rest_for_one`.

You can check its [manual](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html) for further options.